# Java compiler does not recognize derived class, ie, "symbol not found" error

Tags: java, inheritance

I am getting a "cannot find symbol" error when I try to compile this code. In the main, I can create objects of type Ball no problem, but if I try to create object of type Basketball, compiler complains. I am very new to java, please help?

```
class Ball {
    public double radious;
    public String color;

    Ball( double radious, String color ) {
        this.radious = radious;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public double area() {
        return (4 * Math.pow(this.radious, 2) * Math.PI );
    }

    public void display() {
            System.out.println("\nRadious: " + radious );
            System.out.println("Color: " + color );
    }

    class Basketball extends Ball {
        public int noOfStripes;

        Basketball( int n, double r, String c ) {
            super( r, c );
            noOfStripes = n;
        }

        Basketball( double r, String c ) {
            super( r, c );
            noOfStripes = 8; // Default value 
        }

        public void display() {
            super.display();
            System.out.println("Area: " + area() );
            System.out.println("noOfStripes: " + noOfStripes );
        }
    }
}

class Driver {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Ball basket1 = new Ball( 29.5, "Orange" );
        basket1.display();

        Ball basket2 =new Basketball( 29.5, "Black" );
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not create inner classes when you're still learning inheritance.

Comment: Next time post stacktrace and exact specification where the error ouccurs

Comment: @for3st there's no stacktrace. The code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3):

You have created `Basketball` not only as a subclass of `Ball`, but as an inner class as well.  It doesn't need to be an inner class.

Define `Basketball` outside of the braces for the `Ball` class.

```
    }
}  // End of Ball class

class Basketball extends Ball
{
   // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify `BasketBall` with `Ball`:

```
Ball.Basketball basket2 = new Ball.Basketball( 29.5, "Black" );
```

As other comments and answers have pointed out, you should not use inner classes for inheritance. BasketBall should be a separate class:

```
public class BasketBall extends Ball {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Basketball` is an inner class of `Ball` you have to create objectes the following way:

```
Ball.Basketball myBasketball = new Ball().new Basketball(/* foo arguments */);
```

But a better solution would be, to move it outside to be an own class.

Comment: Thank you. Learn something new every day.

Comment: @user2866359 Careful. When using inner classes you need an existing instance of the top class to create an inner class. The right code should be `new Ball().new Basketball(/* foo arguments */);`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Shouldn't have answered in haste... fixed that. Thanks for pointing out :)